# MySql update not recognizing temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, temp-tables

I have the following query script that is resulting in an error:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

Drop Table If Exists testtable2;

Create Temporary Table testtable2
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        row_names, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_add(date_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS date_time, meter, kw
    FROM
        testtable
    WHERE
        DAY(date_time) = 1
            AND HOUR(date_time) = 2) AS testtable2
WHERE
    MOD(testtable2.num, 2) = 0;

UPDATE testtable 
SET 
    testtable.date_time = testtable2.date_time
WHERE
    testtable.row_names = testtable2.row_names;
```

The error says `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'testtable2.row_names' in 'where clause'`

I created a temporary table that contains the column date_time but my update query fails to recognize that the column exists. I can run something like SELECT * FROM testtable2; and it returns showing that the column is indeed generated with the correct title. Why can my update not recognize this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `update` statement:

```
UPDATE testtable 
SET testtable.date_time = testtable2.date_time
WHERE testtable.row_names = testtable2.row_names;
```

What is `testtable`?  You have not defined that.  You created `testtable2`.  If you do have `testtable`, then perhaps you want a `join`:

```
UPDATE testtable tt JOIN
       testtable2 tt2
       ON tt.row_names = tt2.row_names
    SET tt.date_time = tt2.date_time;
```

Comment: testtable is a table I already have in my database. it has the columns row_names, date_time, meter, and kw.

Answer (score 1):

You actually meant to use `CREATE TABLE ... AS` construct but in your case it's wrongly formed. It should be like below.

```
Create Temporary Table testtable2 AS
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        row_names, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num,
      date_add(date_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS date_time, 
      meter, 
      kw
    FROM
        testtable
    WHERE
        DAY(date_time) = 1
            AND HOUR(date_time) = 2) AS XXX <-- Here
WHERE
    MOD(testtable2.num, 2) = 0;
```

Issue in your case is, your Temporary table and inline view alias are same. name them differently. See edited query.

---

You can directly `JOIN` with the inner query and can perform `UPDATE` like

```
UPDATE testtable 
JOIN (
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        row_names, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, date_add(date_time, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS date_time, meter, kw
    FROM
        testtable
    WHERE
        DAY(date_time) = 1
            AND HOUR(date_time) = 2) AS testtable2
WHERE
    MOD(testtable2.num, 2) = 0 ) xx ON testtable.row_names = xx.row_names
SET 
    testtable.date_time = xx.date_time;
```

Comment: I added the AS in my create table but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: I changed the code `AND HOUR(date_time) = 2) AS XXX` to `AND HOUR(date_time) = 2) AS temporarydata` and it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: @DustinKnight, check the edited version of the query without temp table.

Comment: This answer is also correct. According to MySQL Workbench it is approximately 3 tenths of a second slower but may have memory benefits since the temporary table is skipped.